# How to Create a Learning Management Plugin in Wordpress to Manage Courses [LMS]

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, cms

I'm looking to build a small learning management plugin to manage courses

The first feature that i want to implement is the front-end course builder
Meaning that after designing a course page (using it as a default canvas)

[image]

This course builder will do the following:

[Button] -> Create new Course
- Add Course title:
- Add Course Picture:
- Add Sections:
- Add Lectures:
[Button] -> Publish Course

After hitting 'Publish' a course page will be created automatically and added to the database

Any help, tips, assistannce will be greatly appreciated.. I'm stuck for several weeks now

Comment: Your question is rather too broad at the moment. There are several LMS plugins already out there that you could try, or if you're certain you want to build your own, start off with some code and you can ask more specific questions here as you go.

Comment: Thank for answering, I appreciate that :) the problem with the existing plugins is they are not customizable.. All i need is directions from your experts 'Where to start and what to look for in order to create this plugin.. Best Regards :D

Comment: What you are asking for is too broad. It looks like you are asking for someone to do your homework not assist you with a problem. I am creating a highly customizable LMS plugin for Wordpress. There are substantially more things to account for. I would read up on curriculum development so you can fully understand the problem you are asking about and then start with Wordpress custom post types.